turnserver session expires frequently saying closed 2nd stage
I am getting below error while the client is acessing turnserver

173: : ERROR: session 000000000000000006: TLS/TCP socket error: Connection reset by peer 10.139.143.67:21055 173: : session 000000000000000006: usage: realm=<my.domain.com>, username=<>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0 173: : session 000000000000000006: peer usage: realm=<my.domain.com>, username=<>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0 173: : session 000000000000000006: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <my.domain.com> origin <>, local 172.26.16.198:3478, remote >

This is a frequent issue and even the Avatar syn is slow

Check for corresponding entries in the server logs.

Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. See also [ask]

Hi Gerald-I could see in syslog
Apr 15 06:00:14 hostname rsyslogd: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Mon Apr 15 06:00:44 2024, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2112.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]4638: : session 001000000000000034: realm <turnser.mydomain.com> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized

I got this error frequently
4638: : session 001000000000000034: realm <turnser.mydomain.com> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized   and this error
